# Why does this animation not work correctly on the first pass, but does so on all subsequent passes? (React Native)

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, animation

Using React Native, I'm trying to make a perfectly looping animated slideshow with 3 cycling images. For some reason, it doesn't work correctly on the first loop, but does so afterwards.

The problem is that the second time the dragons (first image) appear, it does so instantly because `this.state.imageThreeOpacity` doesn't seem to animate the first time around.

However as the video continues you'll see that it corrects itself.

Here is a video of my slideshow in its current state.: https://streamable.com/tpjcz

Here is my component code. The animation loops with the recursive function `animate`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    View,
    Dimensions,
    Animated,
} from 'react-native';
import _ from 'underscore';
import imageCacheHoc from 'react-native-image-cache-hoc';

const CacheableImage = imageCacheHoc( Image, {
    validProtocols: [ 'http', 'https', '' ]
} );

const animationDistance = 250;

export default class ImageIntro extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();

        this.state = {
            imageOneOpacity: new Animated.Value( 1 ),
            imageTwoOpacity: new Animated.Value( 1 ),
            imageThreeOpacity: new Animated.Value( 1 ),
            imageOneZIndex: 3,
            imageTwoZIndex: 2,
            imageThreeZIndex: 1,
            imageOneTranslateX: new Animated.Value( -( animationDistance / 2 ) ),
            imageOneTranslateY: new Animated.Value( 0 ),
            imageTwoTranslateX: new Animated.Value( animationDistance / 2 ),
            imageTwoTranslateY: new Animated.Value( -( animationDistance / 2 ) ),
            imageThreeTranslateX: new Animated.Value( 0 ),
            imageThreeTranslateY: new Animated.Value( animationDistance / 2 ),
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.animate( true );
    }

    animate( firstPass ) {    
        let {
                imageOneOpacity,
                imageTwoOpacity,
                imageThreeOpacity,
                imageOneTranslateX,
                imageOneTranslateY,
                imageTwoTranslateX,
                imageTwoTranslateY,
                imageThreeTranslateX,
                imageThreeTranslateY
            } = this.state;

        const duration = 2000;
        const delay = 1500;

        setTimeout( () => {
            this.animate( false );
        }, ( duration * 3 ) - ( ( duration - delay ) * 3 ) );

        Animated.parallel(
            [
                Animated.timing(
                    imageOneTranslateX, {
                        toValue: animationDistance / 2,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        duration: duration,
                    }
                ),
                Animated.timing(
                    imageOneOpacity, {
                        toValue: 0,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        delay: delay,
                        duration: duration - delay,
                    }
                ),
            ]
        ).start( () => {
            Animated.timing(
                imageOneTranslateX, {
                    toValue: -( animationDistance / 2 ),
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                    duration: 0,
                }
            ).start();
        } );

        Animated.parallel(
            [
                Animated.timing(
                    imageTwoTranslateX, {
                        toValue: -( animationDistance / 2 ),
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        duration: duration,
                        delay: delay,
                    },
                ),
                Animated.timing(
                    imageTwoTranslateY, {
                        toValue: ( animationDistance / 2 ),
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        duration: duration,
                        delay: delay,
                    },
                ),
                Animated.timing(
                    imageTwoOpacity, {
                        toValue: 0,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        delay: delay * 2,
                        duration: duration - delay,
                    }
                ),
            ]
        ).start( () => {
            Animated.timing(
                imageTwoTranslateX, {
                    toValue: ( animationDistance / 2 ),
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                    duration: 0,
                }
            ).start();
            Animated.timing(
                imageTwoTranslateY, {
                    toValue: -( animationDistance / 2 ),
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                    duration: 0,
                }
            ).start();
            this.setState( { imageThreeZIndex: 4 }, () => {
                Animated.timing(
                    imageOneOpacity, {
                        toValue: 1,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        duration: 0,
                    }
                ).start();
                Animated.timing(
                    imageTwoOpacity, {
                        toValue: 1,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        duration: 0,
                    }
                ).start();
            } );
        } );

        Animated.parallel(
            [
                Animated.timing(
                    imageThreeTranslateY, {
                        toValue: -( animationDistance / 2 ),
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        duration: duration,
                        delay: delay * 2,
                    }
                ),
                Animated.timing(
                    imageThreeOpacity, {
                        toValue: 0,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        delay: delay * 3,
                        duration: duration - delay,
                    }
                ),
            ]
        ).start( () => {
            Animated.timing(
                imageThreeTranslateY, {
                    toValue: ( animationDistance / 2 ),
                    useNativeDriver: true,
                    duration: 0,
                }
            ).start();

            this.setState( { imageThreeZIndex: 1 }, () => {
                Animated.timing(
                    imageThreeOpacity, {
                        toValue: 1,
                        useNativeDriver: true,
                        duration: 0
                    }
                );
            } );

        } );

    }

    render() {
        const { images } = this.props;

        const outputImages = () => {
            let {
                    imageOneOpacity,
                    imageTwoOpacity,
                    imageThreeOpacity,
                    imageOneZIndex,
                    imageTwoZIndex,
                    imageThreeZIndex,
                    imageOneTranslateX,
                    imageOneTranslateY,
                    imageTwoTranslateX,
                    imageTwoTranslateY,
                    imageThreeTranslateX,
                    imageThreeTranslateY
                } = this.state;

            const animationProps = [
                [ imageOneOpacity, imageOneTranslateX, imageOneTranslateY ],
                [ imageTwoOpacity, imageTwoTranslateX, imageTwoTranslateY ],
                [ imageThreeOpacity, imageThreeTranslateX, imageThreeTranslateY ]
            ];

            let output = [];

            _.each( images, ( image, index ) => {
                output.push(
                    <Animated.View key={ `intro-image-${index}` } style={ [ styles.imageWrap, {
                        zIndex: [ imageOneZIndex, imageTwoZIndex, imageThreeZIndex ][ index ],
                        opacity: animationProps[ index ][ 0 ],
                        transform: [
                            { translateX: animationProps[ index ][ 1 ] },
                            { translateY: animationProps[ index ][ 2 ] }
                        ]
                    } ] }>
                        <CacheableImage style={ styles.image }
                                        permanent={ true }
                                        source={ { uri: image } }/>
                    </Animated.View>
                )
            } );

            return output;
        };

        return (
            <View style={ [ styles.container ] }>
                { outputImages() }
            </View>
        );
    }
}

const { width, height } = Dimensions.get( 'window' );

const styles = StyleSheet.create( {
    container: {
        position: 'absolute',
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        zIndex: 1
    },
    imageWrap: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        top: -( animationDistance / 2 ),
        left: -( animationDistance / 2 ),
        width: width + animationDistance,
        height: height + animationDistance
    },
    image: {
        width: width + animationDistance,
        height: height + animationDistance
    }
} );
```

Does anybody see what's causing this?